# How to remove FR or Tax from sale emails?

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

How can I remove FR (20%) or Tax from the sale emails? They are the same thing to me so I want to remove one of them from the emails/ invoices.

```
FR (20%) €48.00
Tax      €48.00
```

If I go the template to look into the code,

```
app/locale/yourlanguage/template/email/sales/order_new.html
```

I see this,

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
```

So I guess this must be where the FR & Tax are generated. So where can I go in the backoffice to configure this?

If I can, it would be better if I can change Tax to something else like Tax FR (20%) - is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tealou,goto

```
app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourTemplate/layout/
```

and open `sales.xml`

find   `<sales_email_order_items>`  and here you find below code

```
<block type="tax/sales_order_tax" name="tax" template="tax/order/tax.phtml">
                    <action method="setIsPlaneMode"><value>1</value></action>
                </block>
```

remove code

Answer (score 1):

Copy app/design/frontend/base/sales/order/totals.phtml to your theme file and open it.
Add the following to the top of it.

```
if($tax = $this->getTotal('tax')){    $this->removeTotal('tax');    $this->addTotal($tax, 'grand_total');}
```